# Print List with Number of Players (Blackjack)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm writing a Blackjack program, but I'm stuck on one part (which is killing me arrghh).

I'm trying to print multiple hands (list) with the corresponding players.

pHands = [['9D', '2H'], ['TS', '2D], etc..] #This is just a shuffled deck

ex. Player n: [3H, TS]

Here's the code:

```
def print_blackjack(pHands, num_of_players):
    for i in pHands:
        for num in range(num_of_players):
            print('Player' + str(num) + ':', i)
    return
```

It returns the hands, but each hand has multiple players associated to it.

I know this is a simple problem, but my mind is giving me a blank.

Any help? Thanks!

Edit*** Here's the full code so far

```
def make_deck():
    # Randomly shuffle a deck
    import random
    cards = []
    for suit in ['H', 'C', 'S', 'D']:
        for num in ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q',
                'K']:
            cards.append(num + suit)
    random.shuffle(cards)
    return cards
deck = make_deck()


num_of_players = int(input("How many players?: "))

def deal_blackjack(deck, num_of_players):
    # Deal two cards to a number of players
    hands = [[] for p in range(num_of_players)]
    i = -1
    for k in range(0,2):
        for h in hands:
            i += 1
            h.append(deck[i])
    return hands

pHands = deal_blackjack(deck, num_of_players)


def print_blackjack(pHands, num_of_players):
    print(list(enumerate(pHands)))
    return
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Can you provide a complete, specific example of what `pHands` contains?  It's not clear from the post.  Also, this function doesn't "return" anything (and in fact, you should delete the useless `return` statement).  What it does is *print* something.

Comment: @TomKarzes pHands is just a shuffled deck with multiple lists containing 2 cards from the the deck. I edited the main question to show what I'm saying. I'm trying to get a loop that shows Player n + the corresponding hand from pHands.

Comment: What's the connection between pHands and Player? Or is there any?

Comment: @Lafexlos The relation being the n in Player corresponds to the number of hand from the pHands list. So Player 0 will show the 0 hand, Player 1 will show the 1 hand.

Comment: @Lafexlos No. It takes the number of inputed players and takes two random cards from a deck for each player. I'll update the main question with the full code.

Comment: Then you don't need `for i in pHands`. Remove that line and use `pHands[num]` instead of `i` when printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
def print_blackjack(pHands):
    for i in range(len(pHands)):
        print('Player', i, ':', pHands[i])
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the parameter **num_of_players** at all: you already know this from the size of the hand list.  Try this:

for i, hand in enumerate(pHands):
        print 'Player', i, ':', hand

Answer (score 1):

If you want to associate player n with pHands[n] in your printing, you can do like this:

```
def print_blackjack(pHands, num_of_players):
    for i in range(num_of_players):
        print('Player' + str(i) + ':', pHands[i])
```

Note: as @TomKarzes wrote, you do not need *return* at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rogalski pointed out, you can use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to generate (number, data) pairs from your `pHands` list.

Try this.

```
def show_hands(hands):
    for num, hand in enumerate(hands):
        print("Player {}: {}".format(num, hand))
```

Output looks like this.

```
Player 0: ['9D', '2H']
Player 1: ['TS', '2D']
```